# Sort by distinct date in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to sort using the months name, when I have it in numbers everything is working, but when I try to make a select like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DATENAME(m, date) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy,date)) as date 
From MyTable
```

In my output I have something like this

```
August, 2015
July, 2015
September, 2015
```

How to sort by month, not by alphabetic order?

I tried to add `order by date` but without any result.
And the output format should be exactly like this.

Comment: You need `order by` to sort in SQL, but you shouldn't sort by your converted value but likely the original value

Comment: I tried and give an error like this `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just embed the query into subquery and select month number along with your string:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( [date] DATE )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '20150701' ),
        ( '20150701' ),
        ( '20150801' ),
        ( '20150901' )

SELECT  [date]
FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), DATENAME(m, [date]) + ', '
                    + DATENAME(yyyy, [date])) AS [date] ,
                    YEAR([date]) AS y ,
                    MONTH([date]) AS m
          FROM      @t
        ) t
ORDER BY t.y, t.m
```

Output:

```
date
July, 2015
August, 2015
September, 2015
```

Comment: This will not work if you have multile years (Ex: 2015 and 2014). It will order by month only, ignoring the year.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a order criteria that you must have in the selected list.
Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DATENAME(m, date) + ', '   + DATENAME(yyyy,date)) as date, 
    year(date) * 100 + month(date) as ordercrit
From 
    MyTable 
order by 
    ordercrit
```

The `ordercrit` should also contain the `year` if you want it to be considered in the ordering, like,

```
January, 2014
February, 2014
January, 2015
May, 2015
January, 2016
```

Comment: Upvote from me but the only sideeffect of this is additional columns in the result. That's why I have used subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Another method

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( [date] DATE )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '20150701' ),
        ( '20150701' ),
        ( '20150801' ),
        ( '20150901' )

SELECT DATE FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), DATENAME(M, DATE) + ', ' + DATENAME(YYYY,DATE)) AS DATE  
FROM      @T
) AS T        ORDER BY CAST(DATE AS DATETIME)
```